# How do I get YouTrack field fixed in build filled out using TeamCity integration?

Tags: teamcity, youtrack

I am trying to get integration between our YoutTrack and our TeamCity working. However I cannot get YouTrack to fill out the "Fixed in build" field:

- Using TeamCity 7.1.3, YouTrack 5.0.2.
- TeamCity integration setup points out the "Build Field" to YT's "Fixed in build"
- YouTrack correctly shows TeamCity builds in tab "TeamCity Changes".
- User names map correctly.
- YouTrack commands by VCS commit comments work correctly.
- Simple YouTrack issue referencing from commit comments works correctly.

However, no matter what I seem do to, the "Fixed in build" field remains at "Next build".

I tried checking the "Add each build to list" in YT setup. Now the build numbers correctly goes into the Build bundle, but still "Fixed in build" is not set. I also tried with both open and closed issues with no effect.

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mention the issue in a commit before you mark the issue as fixed. So when you mark the issue fixed it gets set to next build, and on the next build that succeeds you get the fixed in build set - assuming the build that succeeded was the one linked to that youtrack project.

For the longest time you had to have the issue marked fixed in youtrack before any builds would cause the fixed in build to be set.

So, commit with issue ID, then mark issue fixed in next build. You can refresh the teamcity integration from the issue so it picks up the build.

First I fix the issue in the code. Commit the change to source control. Then in YouTrack - I mark the issue "Fixed"

[image]

You can also manually link the issue to the commit.

[image]

Comment: `when you mark the issue fixed` <-- you might want to clarify exactly what it is you write. Also exactly how do you manually link.

Comment: thats much more helpful now. however, i dont believe you need to mark youtrack as 'Fixed'; you should just be able to commit to your VCS and everything will be done automatically.

Comment: Well then how will it know it is fixed in that build? THe other way is to indicate that you have fixed the issue in the VCS commit by prefixing the issue with # and adding Fixed after. `#IDLua-12 Fixed`

Comment: It might have to be connected to the state the issue is in. You can set what states has the meaning of Resolved/Fixed under the administration section of YouTrack.

Comment: @sylvanaar I'm tying to add an integration between my TeamCity and 
YouTrack but no matter what i do i don't see the "TeamCity Changes" tab, 

where do i add it?