# YouTrack doesn't set "Fixed in build" within TeamCity integration

Tags: teamcity, youtrack

Firstly, I've read [How do I get YouTrack field fixed in build filled out using TeamCity integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569101/how-do-i-get-youtrack-field-fixed-in-build-filled-out-using-teamcity-integration) and [One step YouTrack "Fixed in build" filling with TeamCity integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116356/one-step-youtrack-fixed-in-build-filling-with-teamcity-integration) and it hasn't helped me.
I've configured TeamCity integration in YouTrack and added YouTrack as Issue Tracker in Teamcity. So I'm able to view mentioned issues in TC on Issues tab and there is "VCS Changes" tab in Youtrack and I can see that some issue was mentioned in commit message.

But the issue is - I do not have possibility to set "Fixed in build" field in YT. It neither sets automatically nor manually. It's equal to "Next Build" and that's it. So I wonder how can I:

1. Set "Fixed in build" at least manually.
2. Have this field to be set automatically.

Any ideas?

[image: YT page]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you let the field being set automatically. On %YouTrack%/admin/teamcityIntegrationSettings select the appropriate build configuration mapping. There're two options:

1. Process related issues. It means that it will process resolved issues mentioned in a TeamCity build. 'Mentioned' as it is implemented now means those that TeamCity shows on 'Issues' tab of the build. For this to work you need to configure the integration [on TeamCity](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/YouTrack) side as well.
2. Process issues matching query. It allows you entering a query, and all issues that match it will get their fixed in build field set.

Comment: But how can I set Fixed in Build at least manually? I don't see any builds except "Next Build"

Comment: Try checking Add each build option. If this will result in builds being added to the field's values, then it that the integration generally works fine, but none of the issues you expect to be updated actually match the conditions I mentioned in the answer. If the builds still don't get added to field values, then logs will have the information on what went wrong.

Comment: I don't see such an option, where can I find it? I use YouTrack 6.5

Comment: It's in Mapping properties, in Actions for Default Branch (or Actions for Feature Branch) section.

Comment: I do not have such an option here. There are only "Failed builds", "Related issues", "Issues matching query", "Build field -> Fixed in build" and "Apply command".

Comment: I see. This has been fixed some time ago: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-32764. You can update your YouTrack.